# jquery when getting a input from a table based on data attribute of td why is an error throw when accessing the value of the input

Tags: jquery

I have the following table:

I'm trying to get the firstnames

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>FirstName</th>
      <th>LastName</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-usage="firstname"><input type="text" value="Mike" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-usage="firstname"><input type="text" value="Jo" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I have some jquery:

```
$("#myTable tbody tr td[data-usage='firstname'] input").each(function () {
             alert($(this).value());
         });
```

I was expecting to get two messages one for each name.

instead I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'value'
```

Please can someone explain what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `$(this).val()`. There is no value() function in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery object has no value property, only native DOM nodes do

```
alert( this.value );
```

with jQuery you would be using the `val()` method :

```
alert( $(this).val() );
```

Comment: It's a common mistake, been there !

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$(this).val()` not `$(this).value()`